# How to Run GAMESS and Avogadro on Command Line?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

I always use **GAMESS** and **Avogadro** on my own laptop. Recently I installed them on our university supercomputer and started using them by remote logging-in.

On the laptop everything was super easy but unfortunately I can not find any documentation for using them from **Terminal Command Line** ( I mean sending a job and receiving the result all from Terminal Command Line ).

It would be great if someone knows a good documentation or tutorial for this subject.

Comment: Your using Linux terminal?

Comment: Avogadro isn't a command line program. The best option is to run it on your laptop and transfer files as needed to the facility, by SSH / SCP for example.

Comment: @Mithoron    I use Mac terminal on my laptop endpoint but the other side ( the supercomputer ) is using Linux ( intel ) with these modules : slurm, intel. Ifort. IMIP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Contact the HPC helpdesk at your university or search for some instructions compiled by them.**

We cannot know whether your local cluster uses PBS (TORQUE/MAUI), SLURM or anything else to reserve cores, nodes, memory and cpu time to run jobs.

Comment: Yes you were right.  I called them and received the needed information .  Thanks !